# Python (Django) autocompletion in Vim not working even with right path

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I followed [Sontek's guide](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) and everything was fine until the part about configuring virtual and Django autocomplete. The instructions he gives to get it to work are replicated in every place I looked for answers... The issue I'm having is that the python path is apparently fine, but I can't get autocompletion for any python libs, inside or outside Django.

My Django project folder is like this:

```
- proj
  - bin (this is virtualenv's bin folter)
  - (other folders)
  - src (contains all code, including my settings.py)
```

And my `.vimrc` has this

```
" Add the virtualenv's site-packages to vim path

py << EOF
import os.path
import sys
import vim
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    sys.path.insert(0, project_base_dir)
    activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF
```

I'm calling Vim from the `src` folder using

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=src.settings vim shop/models.py
```

And if I run `:python from django import db` I get no errors at all, which should me it's working, but if I enter somthing like `from django import co` and press `tab` or `ctrl-n` I get

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

I've been trying different plugins and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path
```

Should be:

```
import os
```

I've tried it and it works for me.